The pineapple vendor's problem: sum of extreme pairs from a normally-distributed variable
A fruit vendor wants to sell packages of pineapples, where each package contains two pineapples. He wants the packages to be more or less the same in weight, so he comes up with this idea: put the pineapples in a row sorted by weight, and each time take the lightest and heaviest fruit from the row and package them together, repeating this process until all pairs are packaged.
For simplicity, let's assume that the weight of the pineapples is normally distributed with an average of 1000g and standard deviation of 200g.
What would be the distribution function of the pineapple pairs?

It is easy to see that its average would be 2000g
Intuitively we can expect its standard deviation to be lower than that of the original distribution, but what would it be exactly?
Is the new distribution normal?

Empirically, the plots below show the original vs. new distribution. It is very clear that the standard deviation of the new distribution is a lot smaller, in fact it's about 0.5 - so the pineapple vendor's idea does work. But is there a formula for calculating it?



It is likely to be highly dependent on the number of pineapples you begin with. As the sample size increases, the variance should theoretically decrease.
